# Best practice to upload media files to google cloud

Tags: android, file-upload, google-cloud-platform

I am building a social network mobile app and wanted to host it on google cloud.  I wanted to know whats the practice for uploading photos/videos.

I don't want to send the file through my backend and then to the cloud. I want direct access for uploading and downloading (Although I understand I might have to get an access token from the backend)

Can anyone point me in the right direction of media hosting on google cloud? Is buckets the right tool for the job or am I missing something? or maybe google cloud doesn't have the right tools at all

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Storage(GCS) would be the perfect solution for your use case. You can send files directly to your GCS bucket(they are the basic containers that hold your data, you can think of them as 'Folders'). There are multiple ways for doing this(command line, REST APIs), so check [this link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects).

If you need mobile SDKs you can use [Firebase storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/) instead.